# Images In ListView Don't Match BackColor Property

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, themes

***Overview***

I am currently working on a theme system for my application allowing Light and Dark themes for users to choose from (similar to visual studio). The entire process is pretty straight forward and this is how I am changing the `BackColor` property of the `ListView` control currently (though I have tried a couple inline solutions that failed such as just setting the `BackColor` of the `ListView` and `ListViewItem`).

***Breakdown***

I have an `ImageList` with 6 images; all of which have transparent backgrounds. Each image is of a glass ball of different colors and a drop shadow. I assign one of these six images to each `ListViewItem` within my `ListView` (set to `Details` view) control based on the status I pull from my database.

Everything works great so long as the `ListView` and the `ListViewItem` the image is assigned to keeps its `BackColor` property set to `Color.Control`. If it changes to any other color (green, gray, blue, red, etc.); then the back color of the image does not match. It continues to retain the default `Color.Control` color.

***Theme Code***

```
public static void ApplyTheme(Form f) {
    foreach (Control c in f.Controls) {
        if (c is MenuStrip)
            ThemeMenu((MenuStrip)c);
        else {
            ApplyStyles(c);
            if (c.Controls != null || c.Controls.Count > 0)
                RecurseChildControls(c);
        }
    }
}
public static void RecurseChildControls(Control parent) {
    foreach (Control child in parent.Controls) {
        ApplyStyles(child)

        if (child.Controls != null || child.Controls.Count > 0)
            RecurseChildControls(child);
    }
}
public static void ApplyStyles(Control c) {
    if (c is Button) {
        Button b = (Button)c;
        b.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
        b.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
    }
    if (c is RoundedPanel || c is PictureBox) {
        // Do nothing.
    } else {
        if (c is Label) {
            if (c.Parent is RoundedPanel) {
                // Do nothing.
            } else {
                c.BackColor = BackColor;
                c.ForeColor = ForeColor;
            }
        } else {
            c.BackColor = BackColor;
            c.ForeColor = ForeColor;
        }

        if (c is ListView) {
            ListView lv = (ListView)c;
            if (Style = Themes.Dark)
                lv.GridLines = false;

            foreach (ListViewItem lvi in lv.Items) {
                lvi.BackColor = BackColor;
                lvi.ForeColor = ForeColor;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried adding a single method to update the `BackColor` property of the `ListView` control and all of its `ListViewItem` objects, I then called this method on the `DrawItem` and `DrawSubItem` events (neither worked); called this method in place of the `Invalidate` method of the `ListView`, called this method right after changing the `ImageIndex` property of a `ListViewItem`; I've even tried calling `Invalidate` on the form itself and re-painting everything.

I could really use some guidance on this one since everything else is working out just fine so far; this is the only issue that has me spinning in circles. I've looked through Google several times and never find any results related to the image not having the same `BackColor` as its containing `ListView` or `ListViewItem`. Maybe I'm not performing the search with the right terms, or maybe I'm the first to complain about this issue; who knows. Any help is appreciated.

***NOTE***

If you feel I left out any needed information, or if I should be any clearer on certain things, feel free to comment and let me know so that I can update the clarity of the post for future readers.

***New Attempts (Failures)***

- Tried changing the background color of the `ListView` object before (and after) setting the `ImageIndex` property.
- Tried using `OwnerDraw` and the `DrawItem` event to draw the image.
- Tried creating a `Bitmap` of the original image with a specified background color as below

***Attempt Code***

```
// Bullet 2
e.Graphics.DrawImage(Image, Rectangle);

// Bullet 3
Rectangle r = new Rectangle(0, e.Bounds.Y, 16, 16);
Image I = imageList1.Images[e.Item.ImageIndex];
Bitmap b = new Bitmap(i.Width, i.Height);
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(b)) {
    g.Clear(Theme.BackColor);
    g.DrawImageUnscaledAndClipped(i, new Rectangle(Point.Empty, i.Size));
}
e.Graphics.DrawImage(b, r);
```

***Images***

[Desired Result](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiG6cnGyLrbAhUCnFkKHe7tBTAQjRx6BAgBEAU&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcodemetricsviewer.wordpress.com%2Fpage%2F2%2F&psig=AOvVaw2-BWrpG28jXWAfM3wb8bmS&ust=1528220875800183)

The [Current Result](https://codepen.io/davisj16usmc/pen/aKNbpQ) where the green dot is the image, the red dot is the background issue, and the blue box is the `ListViewItem`.

Comment: Welcome! This is a truely well-written question! - I believe the background color shown below an image with transparency is always the lv backcolor, no matter what the lvitems have unless you ownerdraw it.. Then by calling e.DrawBackground the lvi.backcolor is drawn over the full width, including the space for the image..: `e.DrawBackground();
e.DrawText();
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, e.Bounds.Y, 16, 16);
e.Graphics.DrawImage(imageList1.Images[e.Item.ImageIndex],rect );`

Comment: @TaW Hrmmm... So I did a quick test of the background color theory you just stated and no effect. Going to look into `OwnerDraw` now and I'll post an update. I don't think images with transparency reflect the underlying container controls back color like the `PictureBox` control would.

Comment: @TaW So `OwnerDraw` was also a failure. The image is still retaining that terrible `Color.Control` appearance.

Comment: It seems to work here, but maybe I'm not getting the situation right. Can you post a screenshot and maybe one or two of the images?

Comment: @TaW I wish I could, everything is on a closed off machine with no internet access. I can look into seeing if there is anything on Google Images by chance. Did you use the `DrawItem` event to perform that draw or something else?

Comment: Yes, DrawItem. Which View mode is the lv in? Also: Do you get the wrong colors around the spheres or also on semi-transparent pixels?

Comment: View mode is Details as described above, and it's mostly around; I added two links to the post to help visually describe the issue (had to create a pen/fiddle to demonstrate) and the result I'd like to achieve.

Comment: @TaW can you possibly post a more detailed description of your first comment? Maybe I missed something for the `OwnerDraw`. When I implemented the code you wrote I got exactly what I expected minus the image having a `BackColor` that matches the `ListView`. I know that's how WinForms handles transparency; however, I can't seem to find a single property to help with this issue.

Comment: OK, a few further tests confirm the issue, which only shows when you have semi-tranparent pixels. These get mixed not with the Backcolor of the LVIs but with some grey system color. (Not the LV backcolor nor its parent). The only way to overcome this I can think of, is to create non-tranparent (or at least non-semitransparent) images, maybe on the fly. This involves simply to drawimage the images over a bitmap with the LVIs' backcolor as background. These can be created on the fly in the DrawItem event or, maybe better, stored in a Imagelist and be used without even owner-drawing..

Comment: @TaW seems like way more effort than it's truly worth; I suppose at this point it would come down to the efficiency of that method. I'll look around for some articles and give it a try.

Comment: Yes, indeed. Just prepare the images without transparency and you're good..

Comment: @TaW so I attempted an implementation (will add above soon) that takes the image, creates a `Bitmap` and clears the graphics to the specified `BackColor` (in my testing I used `g.Clear(Color.Tomato)`) then draws the image over that color, I then draw that `Bitmap` to the `ListViewItem` and the result is the same as before, however this definitely clarifies a small piece of information. It would appear the transparent pixels are actually being replaced (even without the `OwnerDraw`) but there is somehow an outline around the object in the image (I'm assuming the semi-transparency you mentioned)

Comment: You can't use bitmaps with a drop shadow created on a specific background, and "transport" them in another background. The Shadow is mixed with original background color and there's nothing you can do about it. Use clean, transparent `.png` images. A converted vector source can be good as well. Limit the external (outside the boundaries of the main image) antialiasing to a minimum, if anything at all. If you need a drop shadow, draw one on the fly.

Comment: @Jimi and @TaW Is it safe to assume at this point that it's maybe just an issue with the `ListView` control itself? I've used the same images in `PictureBox` controls within a `Panel` control and had the expected result with no additional colors. I suppose I may look into adding a `PictureBox` control as the first item instead; or maybe just use `DrawEllipse`; wonder if I can achieve the glass effect with `DrawElipse`. Thank you all for your help, I'll look into using these methods to accomplish my desired result.

Comment: If you don't see artifacts on another surface, it may depend on the color of that surface. How much it's "compatible" with the original background the image was created on. If you draw a shadow on a white background an then paint the bitmap on a darker background, you'll see the artifacts and "stains" pretty well. On a light gray background you might not see it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To show the individual `ListViewItem.BackColors` under the images you need to **owner-draw** or else the `ListView.BackColor` will show instead. But you noticed ugly artifacts in the semi-transparent portions of your images.

After numerous tests I believe that `ImageList` is the culprit.

It seems to insert greyed pixels where semi-tranparent pixels ought to be. Fully transparent pixels are not affected.

This happens independently of its properties.

Here are results of owner-drawing a `ListView` once with an image from an `ImageList` and once drawing the same image, but loaded directly from disk..:

[image][image]

You surely can see which is which..

The image is a yellow blob on transparent background with a semi-transparent halo and two semi-transparent holes.

The drawing code in the `ListView.DrawItem` event is the same:

```
e.DrawBackground();
e.DrawText();
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, e.Bounds.Y, 32, 16);

Bitmap bmp1 = (Bitmap)imageList1.Images[e.Item.ImageIndex];
Bitmap bmp2 = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile("filepath.png");

e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp1_OR_bmp2, rect);
```

**So, if you need semi-tranparency in images you can't really store them in an `ImageList`.**

Comment: Much depends on the quality of the image and the initial settings of the ImageList. If you set its `ColorDepth` to `Depth32Bit` and only after you add the images, the quality is preserved (even if you modify the ImageList `ImageSize` property). If you modify this setting after you have already loaded the images, and the initial setting was the default `Depth8Bit`, the images quality will be quite bad. Specifically, the semi-transparent pixels will not be preserved (there's no way to do it, afterall).

Comment: ... and, in the second case, the semi-transparent pixels will be merged (not sure with what logic) with the current background color of the control that uses the ImageList as a source.

Comment: Wouldn't it be nice if that were true. But it isn't. Imagelist had Depth32Bit before I add the images and still the effect occurs. Just doublechecked.

Comment: I checked it too. I used relatively (for a 32x32 destination) large .png images (500x500) with some shadows (you can find some of them if you google "software icon transparent"). The results are extremely (visibly) different with the settings I described before. A ListView control with a Red background shows the images with a *gray-ish* antialiasing when inserted with the default settings. The "shadow" simply blends with the Red background if loaded with `Depth32Bit`, no matter what the final size. I will test it with lower quality images.

Comment: I can reproduce this using low quality .png images (icons extracted from shell32.dll and converted to .png) and the same icons (.ico files) when added to an ImageList with a `ColorDepth` which doesn't allow an alpha channel. For the .png images, the shadow has to be a fake transparency (a simple color scale/blend simulation).

Comment: I have added the png I made in photoshop for this post. I'll try with larger images later. I suspect the idea is to rather make semi-transparent pixels grey than let am often obnoxious transparentcykey color shine though.-