# TreeView Imagelist showing with white borders

Tags: c#, winforms

The behavior I'm getting:

[image]

The expected behavior:

[image]

I'm passing the parent backcolor from the main form to both the TreeView and UserControl that the treeView is inside. However, it seems like that's still not functioning.... Why do I keep getting the white borders even though the pics are PNG and has transparent background.

Comment: The focus is on the control. If you change the focus to another object the border should go away.

Comment: PNG supports transaprency, which also means it 'supports' anti-aliased semi-transparent pixels, which usually cause this. You need to get rid of them! See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50684959/images-in-listview-dont-match-backcolor-property/50688895#50688895) and for a helper function [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43372549/remove-outline-from-image-on-transparent-form/43373628#43373628)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to alter ColorDepth property of the ImageList? This worked to me:

```
imageList.ColorDepth = ColorDepth.Depth32Bit;
```

[Related Question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28801793/weird-white-outline-around-c-sharp-images/65415648#65415648)

Comment: `treeView1.ImageList.ColorDepth = ColorDepth.Depth32Bit;`